# I wanted to develop a map reduce logic to find sentence count form the input file

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I am new to hadoop and have basic idea of map reduce , the input to the map function will be key and value pair. So how do i basically identify when my sentence is completed and how can i count it. Is default input format that is TextInput format can be used or can we use some other input format to do it in a easier way.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you'd just check the line for periods.  Decide whether an elipses (...) should be ignored, etc.  Then as each line is passed to the map() method, you'd write out a key/value counting those legitimate periods to the context.  The definition of what it means to end a sentence is your call.  The logic to do that should be straightforward.

You can make it so that entire sentences are passed, one at a time, to the map() method, but that's much harder to do.  You basically take that same logic and put it in a new input format type and corresponding RecordReader.  If you have a choice go with the logic in the map() method and not the input format type and record reader.

Comment: Can we make the input format in such a way that sentence are sent as value .